# Deserialize Json to Pojo without case sensitivity

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, pojo

I have been trying to figure out how to deserialize json coming from an API response to models and ignore case.  I can get it to work with something like this:

Json:

```
{
    "Name": "foo"
}
```

Model:

```
@Data
public class Member {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
}
```

I have SOOOO many because for some reason the API returns properties in pascal case rather than camel. I dont really want to create a new mapper for something so trivial.  I was hoping there was some property in spring boot that I could add to my applicaition yaml file.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is always better to follow naming conventions to avoid such issues.

Comment: i dont have control over the apis im calling out to.  i also dont want to name my variables to match their poor naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring like below it will work :)

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
private String name;
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it in the yaml but this works as well :)   i can put this on each class level and that will take care of all properties.  nice!

Comment: yes you can use it at class level as well.